# Replace values by NaN in certain rows of a pandas df given a specific condition in another df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this initial df

```
xpos = pd.DataFrame({'N': [1, 2, 3, 4],'Type': [External, External, Internal, Internal]})
```

And then I have this other one

```
L = pd.DataFrame({'N': [1, 2, 3, 4],'Length': [100, 300, 400, 200]})
```

In dataframe 'L' I need to change the values in column named 'Length' by 'NaN' for every row in first dataframe 'xpos' defined as 'External'.
This means substituting 100 and 300 by 'NaN'. This is meant to work with a larger dataframe so I cannot change the values individually and it should detect which value of the 'N' column is external and change its length to 'NaN'

I have tried with a loop for but it is not going well

```
for i in range (0, len(xpos)):       
    if xpos.loc[i,'Type'] == 'External':
        VLDext=xpos.loc[i, 'N']
        L.loc[VLDext, 0]='NaN'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of what I have understood, we are based on the values of `xpos Type as External` we need to update `Length column in L as nan`.

We are merging `L and xpos on column N` and then based on `Type External in xpos` we are updating `Length of L by nan`.

**Code**

```
L['Length'] = np.where(L.merge(xpos, on='N', how='inner').Type == 'External',np.nan,L.Length)
```

**Output**

```
    N   Length
0   1   NaN
1   2   NaN
2   3   400.0
3   4   200.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is much easier than what I was trying

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the two data frames have the same length and are aligned on `N`:

```py
mask = xpos['Type'] == 'External'
L.loc[mask, 'Length'] = np.nan
```

Comment: Unfortunately I will have changes in the length further on but thanks for your help. Already made it work with answer given by Uts